# QTextStream не видит табулятор перехода, строки

Tags: c++, qt

В общем создал код

//-----------------------

```
 dump_fid_hf.name_fri = "SK0.bin";
    str.append(QString("%1 *%2\n").arg(dump_fid_hf.name_fri).arg("Имя файла результата измерений (ФРИ)"));
    dump_fid_hf.name_fri = "FID.txt";
    str.append(QString("%1 *%2\n").arg(dump_fid_hf.name_fid).arg("Имя файла исходных данных (ФИД)"));

    QString fileName =global_qwerty + '/' + dump_fid_hf.name_fri;


    QFile file(fileName);
    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        QTextStream out(&file);
        out.setCodec("UTF-8");
        out <<str;
        file.close();

        if (out.status() != QTextStream::Ok) {
            qDebug() << "Ошибка записи файла";
        }
    }
```

все хорошо кроме того что он должен был сделать

SK0.bin *Имя файла результата измерений (ФРИ)

FID.txt  *Имя файла исходных данных (ФИД)

а он сделал  **SK0.bin *Имя файла результата измерений (ФРИ)
 FID.txt *Имя файла исходных данных (ФИД)**

// ---------------------------------------------

В общем он не отрабатывает \n . Как его этому научить ????

Comment: Вы на какой платформе работаете? Попробуйте `\r\n`.

Comment: Qt Creator в нем работаю

Comment: Платформа: Windows, Linux, Mac... Или попробуйте так: `out << "string" << endl;` Так Qt подставит нужный конец строки в зависимости от платформы.

Comment: сработало :3 \r\n                      . спасибо, оформите как ответ я поставлю "правильный ответ"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените `file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)` на `file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)`, в этом случае перенос строки будет автоматически заменен на используемый в данной конкретной платформе.

Описание флага `QIODevice::Text` из документации:

> When reading, the end-of-line terminators are translated to '\n'. When writing, the end-of-line terminators are translated to the local encoding, for example '\r\n' for Win32.